# Groupby covariance between two columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

Given a Dataframe df, here it is the subset of my original dataframe.

```
Transportation_Mode time_delta  trip_id segmentid   Vincenty_distance   velocity       acceleration       jerk
         walk           1          1        1          1.551676553     1.551676553     0.550163852    -1.017629555
         walk           1          1        1          1.70920675      1.70920675      0.16257622     -0.39166534
         walk           1          1        1          1.871782971     1.871782971    -0.22908912     -0.734438511
         walk          12          1        1          23.16466284     1.93038857      0.324972586    -0.331839143
         walk           1          1        1          5.830059603     5.830059603    -3.657097132     2.614438854
         bus            1         16        5          8.418372046     8.418372046    -7.259019484     7.40735053
         bus           23         16        5          26.66510892     1.159352562     0.148331046    -0.036318522
         bus            1         16        5          4.570966614     4.570966614    -0.68699497     -0.889126918
```

I want to calculate covariance between velocity and accelration on groupby, resultant dataframe df1 look like this

```
Trip_id Segmentid   Transportation_Mode  Covariance
   1        1          walk            
   16       1          bus
```

I am trying to solve using this way

```
grp = df.groupby(['trip_id','Transportation_Mode','segmentid'])
df1['Covariance'] = grp.apply(lambda x: x['velocity'].cov(x['acceleration']))
```

But it given an error,

```
  TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

The detailed code is given below

```
grp = df.groupby(['userid','trip_id','Transportation_Mode','segmentid'])
df = grp.filter(lambda x: len(x)>3) # filter all groups whose length is  greater than 3

#get top1 and top2 values
f1 = lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False).iloc[0]
f1.__name__ = 'Top_1'
#for top2 return nan if not exist
f2 = lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False).iloc[1]
f2.__name__ = 'Top_2'

f3 = lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False).iloc[2] 
f3.__name__ = 'Top_3'

f5 = lambda x: len(x[x<3.4]) # count the stop points with velocity less than threshold value 3.4
f5.__name__ = 'stop_frequency'

f6 = lambda x: len(x[x>0.2]) # count the points with velocity greater than threshold value 0.2
f6.__name__ = 'frequency'

f7 = lambda x: len(x[x>0.25]) # count the points with accelration greater than threshold value 0.25
f7.__name__ = 'frequency'

f8 = lambda x: x.quantile(0.85)
f8.__name__ = '85_percentile'

d = {'date_time':['first','last', 'count'], 
 'acceleration':['mean', f1, f2, f3,'count', f8, 'median', 'min'], 
 'velocity':[f1, f2, f3, f5, 'sum' ,'count', f8, 'median', 'min'], 
 'velocity_rate':f6,
 'acc_rate':f7,          
 'Vincenty_distance':'sum'}

df1 = df.groupby(['userid','trip_id','Transportation_Mode','segmentid'], sort=False).agg(d)

#flatenning MultiIndex in columns
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)
#MultiIndex in index to columns
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

Now I want to calculate covariance between velocity and acceleration, in which 2 columns are involved. So don't know how to do this in aggregate function? or create a separate columns for this.

```
df_cv = pd.DataFrame()
df_cv['Covariance'] = grp.apply(lambda x: x['velocity'].cov(x['acceleration']))
df_cv = df_cv.reset_index()
df1['cov'] = df_cv['Covariance']
```

when I attach covariance column, the groups are not aligned. on row 15, the group (userid=141, trip_id=10, Transportation_Mode=subway, segmentid=2) is attached  with covariance of group  (userid=141, trip_id=1, Transportation_Mode=walk, segmentid=1)

Complete input data for dataframe df is available at the link 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JjvS7igTmrtLA4E5Rs5D6tsdAXqzpYqX/view

Comment: Works just fine for me.  Seems like the error occurs when you try to assign it to `df1`.  Hard to diagnose without seeing `DF1`

Comment: yes it works well as standalone, but I also want to assign this to df1

Comment: I modify the question and provide more detailed code with data, that may help you understand the problem better. @user3483203

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please examine the following code:

```
grp = df.groupby(['trip_id','Transportation_Mode','segmentid'])
df_cv = pd.DataFrame()
df_cv['Covariance'] = grp.apply(lambda x: x['velocity'].cov(x['acceleration']))
```

This will provide following dataframe:

```
                                       Covariance
trip_id Transportation_Mode segmentid            
1       walk                1           -3.161471
16      bus                 5          -13.650859
```

Please note that the index of the dataframe is `[trip_id Transportation_Mode segmentid]`, which comes from the previous `groupby` operation. In your original `df1` the index is different, that is the source of the error. So you need to match indices, for example if `df1` has "normal" index , by

```
df_cv = df_cv.reset_index()
df1 = df1.append(df_cv)
```

or by other type of `merge` operation

Comment: How is this different than what he does in his question, apart from creating a random empty dataframe?

Comment: Exactly as you noted, it creates the dataframe **before** assigning something to one of its columns

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with the error he is getting.  If he didn't create the dataframe he would get `name 'DF1' is not defined`

Comment: The solution I applied but now it is giving logical error. Now I modify the question and provide you detailed code with data, that may help you understand the problem better. @igrinis

Comment: I make little improvement in your code to make the result right. merge operation was required instead of append. In fact, it was one to one mapping between two dataframes based on column matching.